# Is it okay to have a function as an Angular service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Usually AngularJS services are objects - no matter whether you create them using `service`, `factory` or `provider`.

Now I have a use case for a singleton function. Basically, I *could* solve this using a call to `factory` and by returning the function, such as:

```
angular.module('foo')
  .factory('bar', function () {
    return function () {
      // ...
    };
  });
```

This works, and whenever I ask for `bar` I get the inner-most function. Anyway, the fact that it *works* does not mean that it's a good idea.

So, is it? Or is it a bad one? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `value` or `constant`? According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) they can take functions too.

> Register a constant service, such as a string, a number, an array, an
> object or **a function**, with the $injector.

also from the docs of value:

> This is short for registering a service where its provider's $get
> property is a factory function that takes no arguments and returns the
> value service.

So I assume your approach is also valid.